# jquery forms plugin noConflict problem

Tags: jquery, bookmarklet, jquery-forms-plugin

I am writing a bookmarklet in which I want to use the jquery forms plugin.

The problem I am having is that a web page on which the bookmarklet might be used could be using a different js lib, which already uses '$'. No problem, I can tell jQuery to use noConflict()

However, the forms plugin of jQuery also uses '$' which I have no control over. Is there a way for me to specify to this plugin to not use $ and use jQuery instead?

More details..

As TNi suggests, I might be misunderstanding the problem.

Here is what I do

I am using Safari 5. Here is what I do
(jquery already loaded)
....

```
var scriptElem = docEl.createElement('script');
scriptElem.setAttribute('src',"http://localhost:81/p/a2b/jquery.form.js");
scriptElem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElem);
```

and then

```
jQuery(docEl).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#a2b_cart').ajaxForm(function () { alert (" yo");});
```

});

What I see on the javascript console:

```
jQuery("#a2b_cart").ajaxForm is not a function
```

Comment: What is the difference between `docEl` and `document` in your script? You create the element with `docEl` but then append it to `document`. Are they not equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, your code initializing the form is called immediately after adding the `script` element, but before it has loaded. Since jQuery is already loaded, call the forms file via [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
jQuery.getScript("http://localhost:81/p/a2b/jquery.form.js", function () {
    jQuery('#a2b_cart').ajaxForm(function () { alert("yo"); });

    // Rest of your code here, or call out to another function
});

// Don't place code here, form.js hasn't loaded yet.
```

The callback function will only be run once the script file has loaded.

Comment: Thanks Doug(and TNi). That was the problem

Answer (score 2):

The [Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) uses a technique that allows it to use `$` locally within its own code without conflicting with any calls to `jQuery.noConflict()`.

When you are setting up your form to be handled by the plugin, just use `jQuery` in place of `$`. If the problem still persists, we will need to see specific code in order to help.

Comment: TNi, 
thanks for the response. I have added more details. It is possible that I have a different problem, based on the info you provided.